# Flatten Lookup<TKey,TValue> to key-value pairs

Tags: c#, linq

`lookup.SelectMany(x => x)` only returns values. Is there a way to retain keys associated with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Lookup<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=net-6.0) implements `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TElement>>` and [`IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=net-6.0) exposes [`Key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2.key?view=net-6.0) property so just use it:

```cs
var listOfValueTuples = lookup
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(v => (g.Key, v)))
    .ToList();
```